# Working on a Common Lisp Jupyter notebook server - and experiencing a crash in ipython code

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter

I am working on the cl-jupyter system (a Jupyter notebook kernel for Common Lisp - in collaboration with Frederic Peschanski) to add jupyter widgets.  We have added support for jupyter widgets 7.0 and we have added support for 'nglview', a jupyter widget for visualizing molecules.

I am encountering a problem that appears to be a threading issue. When I evaluate input cells (shift-enter) slowly, one after another - everything works fine. When I evaluate cells in rapid succession (shift-enter) within the jupyter notebook, I get an error and a backtrace from the PYTHON jupyter client! There is no problem in the Common Lisp code.  The backtrace suggests that there was a problem with message signing but it looks to me like more than one thread is injecting text into the message.

I am unclear as to how the PYTHON jupyter client even enters into the picture.  I thought the Common Lisp kernel communicated directly with the browser.  But I suppose something must send the javascript code to the browser.

I'd love to talk to someone about what might be going on under the hood and how I might approach fixing this.

Backtrace follows:

```
[Shell] top of main loop
[Shell] top of main loop
[Shell] top of main loop
[Shell] top of main loop
[E 22:37:45.606 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/efa66e9c-2964-468e-ac1c-f3a160c9ea24/channels?session_id=EEDF893B785540728F1632EED7969035 (::1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='localhost:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/efa66e9c-2964-468e-ac1c-f3a160c9ea24/channels?session_id=EEDF893B785540728F1632EED7969035', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='::1', headers={'Upgrade': 'websocket', 'Connection': 'Upgrade', 'Host': 'localhost:8888', 'Origin': 'http://localhost:8888', 'Cookie': '_xsrf=2|f7610529|4eb65ee3b9ca2742109faeef27ae7f1d|1512343173', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Sec-Websocket-Key': 'h/2hVsgCgp7bQouBzmEDzA==', 'Sec-Websocket-Version': '13', 'Sec-Websocket-Extensions': 'x-webkit-deflate-frame', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/604.4.7 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/11.0.2 Safari/604.4.7'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1425, in _stack_context_handle_exception
        raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 191, in <lambda>
        self.on_recv(lambda msg: callback(self, msg), copy=copy)
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 299, in _on_zmq_reply
        msg = self.session.deserialize(fed_msg_list)
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 902, in deserialize
        raise ValueError("Invalid Signature: %r  check: %r  self.key: %s    msg_list[0:5]: %s" % (signature, check, self.key, list(msg_list[0:5])))
    ValueError: Invalid Signature: b'5bef6d6ed9017584a7278c7a6ba36ab6b34f0c08a3cc4a8fa3d0dddea7596d2a'  check: b'8ca9da17ff933d6bcc172bfb24aa839ccf263be2b1e3309f66c76f499073a66a'  self.key: b'f4a3d14d-3d3c9527fd37fa880800a466'    msg_list[0:5]: [b'5bef6d6ed9017584a7278c7a6ba36ab6b34f0c08a3cc4a8fa3d0dddea7596d2a', b'{"msg_id": "BD40C37A-B4CE-4D7E-97E1-C952DC580BEF","username": "username","session": "C1F347B35D82477D8214F19AF2071668","msg_type": "comm_msg","version": "5.0"}', b'{"msg_id": "9DEC24D5A6CF4AB68371D72660361627","username": "username","session": "C1F347B35D82477D8214F19AF2071668","msg_type": "execute_request","version": "5.0"}', b'{}', b'status']
[E 22:37:45.731 NotebookApp] Uncaught exception GET /api/kernels/efa66e9c-2964-468e-ac1c-f3a160c9ea24/channels?session_id=C1F347B35D82477D8214F19AF2071668 (127.0.0.1)
    HTTPServerRequest(protocol='http', host='0.0.0.0:8888', method='GET', uri='/api/kernels/efa66e9c-2964-468e-ac1c-f3a160c9ea24/channels?session_id=C1F347B35D82477D8214F19AF2071668', version='HTTP/1.1', remote_ip='127.0.0.1', headers={'Host': '0.0.0.0:8888', 'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10.12; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0', 'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8', 'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 'Sec-Websocket-Version': '13', 'Origin': 'http://0.0.0.0:8888', 'Sec-Websocket-Extensions': 'permessage-deflate', 'Sec-Websocket-Key': '0Fxxh4O0hoYMmdO2rBOTJA==', 'Cookie': '_xsrf=2|ebedd344|91b249d904fc164e70b3252d5309c610|1511624179', 'Connection': 'keep-alive, Upgrade', 'Pragma': 'no-cache', 'Cache-Control': 'no-cache', 'Upgrade': 'websocket'})
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/web.py", line 1425, in _stack_context_handle_exception
        raise_exc_info((type, value, traceback))
      File "<string>", line 3, in raise_exc_info
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 314, in wrapped
        ret = fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-pac[kages/zmq/eventloop/zmqstream.py", line 191, in <lambda>
        self.on_recv(lambda msg: callback(self, msg), copy=copy)
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/notebook/services/kernels/handlers.py", line 299, in _on_zmq_reply
        msg = self.session.deserialize(fed_msg_list)
      File "/Users/meister/anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jupyter_client/session.py", line 902, in deserialize
        raise ValueError("Invalid Signature: %r  check: %r  self.key: %s    msg_list[0:5]: %s" % (signature, check, self.key, list(msg_list[0:5])))
    ValueError: Invalid Signature: b'5bef6d6ed9017584a7278c7a6ba36ab6b34f0c08a3cc4a8fa3d0dddea7596d2a'  check: b'8ca9da17ff933d6bcc172bfb24aa839ccf263be2b1e3309f66c76f499073a66a'  self.key: b'f4a3d14d-3d3c9527fd37fa880800a466'    msg_list[0:5]: [b'5bef6d6ed9017584a7278c7a6ba36ab6b34f0c08a3cc4a8fa3d0dddea7596d2a', b'{"msg_id": "BD40C37A-B4CE-4D7E-97E1-C952DC580BEF","username": "username","session": "C1F347B35D82477D8214F19AF2071668","msg_type": "comSm_msg","version": "5.0"}', b'{"msg_id": "9DEC24D5A6CF4AB68371D72660361627","username": "username","session": "C1F347B35D82477D8214F19AF2071668","msg_type": "execute_request","version": "5.0"}', b'{}', b'status']hell] top of main loo
p
[Shell] top of main loop
```

Comment: The only tangible information you offer is python backtrace. What does this have to do with Lisp?